# Can conservation of momentum be applied before and after a particle is acted on by a force?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum, conservation-laws

Suppose a body is moving with a velocity of $v_0$, and then a force acts on it for a certain period of time, after which the velocity of the body changes to $v_1$.

Can be the conversation of linear momentum applied to time *before* force acts, and time *after* the force has acted?

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: Yes, provided you remember that [impulse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impulse_(physics)) is equal to change in momentum.

Answer (score 1):

It's best to think of conservation of momentum as a restatement of Newton's third law.  So, when object one applies a force to object two, and changes its velocity, it will be necessary that object two applies and equal and opposite force to object one, and consequently, object one's velocity will change too.

It will work out in such a way that the overall momentum of object one and object two will not change.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong but I don't think it is necessarily true that "consequently, object one's velocity will change too".  It depends on the reference frame. Let's say I push a box to the right on a frictionless table giving it a velocity to the right with respect to the floor. Per Newton 3 the box exerts an equal and opposite force on me to the left but I do not do not acquire a velocity to the left with respect to the floor because of an equal and opposite static friction force between my feet and the floor. The net force on me is zero.

Comment: The above not withstanding, if you consider a reference frame other than the earth, momentum is still conserved. Considering the earth and I together, the equal and opposite force the box exerts on us gives us an equal and opposite momentum than the box, so the total change in momentum is zero and momentum is conserved before and after I push the box.

Comment: @BobD: you don't move because you are in contact with the floor, and the floor stops you.  Now, you move the floor in the opposite direction in which you pushed it, so technicaqlly, you're moving the earth to the other direction.  The thing is, the mass of the earth is so large that its change in velocity will nto be measurable.

Comment: Jerry, I think we are essentially saying the same thing if you look at my second comment. But when it comes to conservation of momentum,  I consider, me, the floor and the earth, and not just the floor, moving as one with velocity to the left  with respect to a frame of reference other than the earth. Our combined velocity to the left, albeit minuscule, is what conserves momentum. My only reservation about your answer is you don't say what is the frame of reference with respect to which the two velocities are measured. Thanks for considering my comment. Bob

Comment: @BobD: if the Earth, both before and after the collision is your "frame of reference", and we are caring about the small change in the Earth's velocity, then you have choosen an accelerating frame of reference, and Newton's laws will not be valid.